# Xcode Error: Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked by passcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, testing

I encountered an error while trying to **test my iOS App on a Physical Device** via **WiFi** (no cable connection!)

*Here are the **error message** & the **error description***

> **Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked by passcode.**

> allowsSecureServices: 1. isConnected: 0. Platform: DVTPlatform:0x7f9d3df95a50:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7f9d3df959d0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>. DTDKDeviceIdentifierIsIDID: 0

[image: Image of The Error]

Does anyone of you have an idea what causes this error and how to fix it? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try to
1- unpair device 
2- pair again using the cable 
3- make sure to set connect via network as picture below 
4- try to run now 
[connect via network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E72Jd.png)

Comment: doesn't work for me xcode12.2, iPhone 11 ProMax iOS14.1